# Selectively Accept Client Certificates in ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a request to allow customers to select to authenticate to our service using mTLS (Mutual Authentication). The problem I have is I want to allow this only on one endpoint and only in special circumstances. I do not want to globally accept or require Client Certificates on each request. The setting in IIS allows Ignore, Accept, or Require.

[image]

When I set it to Accept and browse to the site in Chrome I get this pop-up

[image]

Is there a way to accept the certificates if they are passed to a specific endpoint but not change the behavior of other endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable [SSL Negotiation settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access) on a specific route you can apply that setting to a specific location

```
<location path="Route/Goes/Here">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Depending on how your IIS is setup this may cause a 500 error saying "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level." If that happens you need to enable the SSL Settings Read/Write flag as seen here:

[image: SSL Settings Read/Write]

Or using Powershell:

```
Set-WebConfiguration  //System.WebServer/Security/access[@sslFlags] -metadata overrideMode -value Allow -PSPath IIS:/
```

Comment: This is exactly what we do.  But I believe this answer to be a duplicate.